# ActiveModel search by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, activemodel

I've seen similar questions but nothing exactly like mine. I apologize if this is a duplicate - if it is, please refer me to answer(s).

I need to search orders by customer names, and the link between the two is users. Here are my models:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :customer
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm trying to search using:

```
@orders = Order.joins(:user).joins(:customers).where('last_name LIKE ?', name[0])
```

But I get the error message -

*Can't join 'Order' to association named 'customers'; perhaps you misspelled it?*

I'm sure I don't have the associations right, but I'm not sure how to do it. Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Maybe `Order.joins(:users)...` (plural).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this.

```
Order.joins(user: [:customer]).where(customer: {last_name: name[0]})
```

I took help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489017/rails-activerecord-query-based-on-association-value) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873065/rails-returning-all-of-second-level-association)

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much to you all. Just had to change customer: to customers: in the second reference

    @orders = Order.joins(user: [:customer]).where(customers: {last_name: name[0]})

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. @Steve Will you accept this answer if it helped you in any way? Thanks.